# Select multi rows contains a special value in multi columns

Tags: python

I have a df, like

```
   Person  1st    2nd          3rd 
0   A     Park    Gym          Supermarket
1   B     Tea     Restaurant   Park  
2   C     Coco    Gym          Beer
... ...   ...     ...          ...
```

If I want to select and get a new df which rows contains 'Park'.
Desired result:

```
   Person  1st    2nd          3rd 
0   A     Park    Gym          Supermarket
1   B     Tea     Restaurant   Park
...
```

another new df which rows contains 'Gym'.
Desired results:

```
   Person  1st    2nd          3rd 
0   A     Park    Gym          Supermarket 
2   C     Coco    Gym          Beer
...
```

How could I do it?

There is no problem to select park in one column, df.[df['1st'] == 'park'] but have problems to select from multi columns 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas filter data frame rows by function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51589573/pandas-filter-data-frame-rows-by-function)

Comment: not really. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform "or" operations in pandas by using the pipe `|`, so in this specific case, you could try:

```
df_filtered = df[(df['1st'] == 'park') | (df['2nd'] == 'park') | (df['3rd'] == 'park')]
```

Alternatively, you could use the `.any()` function with the argument `axis=1` which will return a row where there is any match:

```
df_filtered = df[df[['1st', '2nd', '3rd']].isin(['park']).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The second solution with isin and .any worked out!  The first solution with | did not work out, as it mentioned: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'bool'